# For Redis to store hashes efficiently using 'hash-max-ziplist-entries' do keys need to be integers as well?

Tags: redis

Redis allows for key/value-pairs to be stored efficiently in a hash if numbers of kv-pairs stays below `hash-max-ziplist-entries`.

A prereq. seems to be that values are integers. Is it also required that keys are integers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to both. Redis v6 example that shows you don't need integers:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset h a b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> OBJECT ENCODING h
"ziplist"
```

Note: in v7, hashes use listpacks.

Comment: Oh nice. Didn't know the `Object`-command